# No /var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst in Buster

Tags: debian, dash, debootstrap

In https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap#Steps_for_Squeeze_and_later, it's required to run the following command in chroot environment:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst install
```

This command runs in Stretch, however there is no `/var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst` file found in Buster.

What might be the equivalent command to complete the installation in Buster?

## Reproduction

```
git clone https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-example
cd multistrap-example
./build.sh buster
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dash.preinst` [was removed a year ago](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dash/commit/020393f77a74ded57ee1bc3f1389ea0833dc5b09), because it was no longer necessary — its purpose was to ensure that `/bin/sh`’s ownership could switch between `bash` and `dash`, but `bash` stopped shipping `/bin/sh`.

The equivalent command is nothing, you don’t need to run the `preinst` any more.